# How to correctly infer vectors in Gensim doc2vec?

Tags: python, gensim, similar-documents

I would like to know which is the correct procedure for inferring vectors in *Gensim doc2vec*.

I have a dataframe `df` with a feature, called `name`, and composed of two subsets `train` and `test`.

`df = train + test`

My aim is to find the most similar `name` in `train` given a `name` in `test`.
For doing this I have to train the *doc2vec* model, and I have two possible choices:

- train the model on the entire `df` and then infer the most similar `name` by `model.infer_vector()` on `test`.
- train the model on `train`, **letting out** `test`, and then use `model.infer_vector()` on `test`.

I suppose that the correct procedure is first one, but I am not sure.

Also, so doing, there is the possibility that the most similar `name`  given `test` will be again in `test` and not in `train`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the first approach, given that both train and test are known, there is no need of generalization i.e. you don't expect unseen vectors.

In order to avoid the problem you mentioned, you have to find the most similar vector to a vector in `test` considering  only vectors in `train`. For example:

```
train = [v1, v2, v3]
test = [v4, v5]
most_similar = {}
for vector in test:
most_similar[vector] = v1
  for vector2 in train:
   if similarity(vector2, vector) > similarity(most_similar[vector], vector):
     most_similar[vector] = vector2
```

In the end in `most_similar` you have the most similar vector in train for each vector in test.